# 18.04 or 19.04 on Samsung NVMe SSD → Bus errors

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 19.04, nvme

Beforehand:

- Did update BIOS (MB: [Asus Z390-F](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z390-F-GAMING/specifications/))
- Did update NVMe SSD firmware (Samsung 970 EVO Plus, 500G)
- Did run `memtest86` for hours (after the problems happened: is OK)
- CPU is [Intel i5-9400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134898/intel-core-i5-9400-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) providing [UHD Graphics 630](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/uhd_graphics/630)
- UEFI boot
- Not overclocking
- BIOS is all "optimized defaults", except for Wake On LAN (On), "Download and install Armory Crate" (Off)
- The MB (motherboard) has nothing else (no CD, no graphic card...)

**Ubuntu install** ( The SSD was supposed to be dedicated to Ubuntu 18.04 )

- Installed fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Selected "Update while installing" + "Install 3rd party drivers..."
- Did manual partitioning, all ext4 (then tried also "Erase disk and install")
- → Install had a "crash", is "sorry" and "click to reboot"

So, tried again, the whole thing, without "Update while installing" & "Install 3rd party drivers..." (removed the network to be sure)

- this time it went through
- Then did `apt update ; apt upgrade`
- Reboot
- Then after a while, using Ubuntu GUI, suddenly pages and pages of that

*Edit, `dmesg` excerpt:*

```
[  109.632452] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[  109.632466] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  109.632474] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:a330] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  109.632479] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  134.215214] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[  134.215219] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  134.215222] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:a330] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  134.215224] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  144.288685] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0xffffffff, PCI_STATUS=0x10
[  144.320962] print_req_error: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 111572600 flags 80700
[  144.344627] nvme 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  144.344951] nvme nvme0: Removing after probe failure status: -19
[  144.369035] print_req_error: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 127856976 flags 801
[  144.369062] print_req_error: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 332338688 flags 801
[  144.369075] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme0n1p8): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 16253466 (offset 0 size 233472 starting block 41542393)
[  144.369079] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70080
[  144.369099] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70081
[  144.369103] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70082
[  144.369106] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70083
[  144.369110] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70084
[  144.369113] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70085
[  144.369116] Aborting journal on device nvme0n1p5-8.
[  144.369118] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70086
[  144.369121] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70087
[  144.369124] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70088
[  144.369127] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1p8, logical block 70089
[  144.369136] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5901: Journal has aborted
[  144.369140] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 3178496, lost sync page write
[  144.369144] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for nvme0n1p5-8.
[  144.369164] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[  144.369169] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): I/O error while writing superblock
[  144.369173] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  144.369245] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme0n1p5): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 1311005 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 31736)
```

get displayed. Had to reset the PC.

Initially I was looking at a bad NVMe SSD, but...

**Windows 10 trial-install**. So I installed Windows 10 (the free ISO) to confirm the problem is the SSD (Samsung supports only Windows)

- taking the whole disk,
- creating as many partitions as what was on Ubuntu
- did the MS updates
- did a stress test on all partitions, copying files over and over, filling the partitions
- rebooted many times
- → No errors anywhere, nothing in the s.m.a.r.t log (Samsung magician)

Therefore, it seems hard to blame the SSD.

**Ubuntu 19.04 install**. Then, on the data partitions created in Windows (except the one where Windows is) I installed Ubuntu **19.04** (not 18.04), thus these parts went from `ntfs` to `ext4`.

- All went fine
- Did `apt update && apt upgrade`
- Reboot
- Using Ubuntu,
- → then same as before, pages and pages of the same messages as above
- → Reboot: goes to Grub "shell"

Booting (from BIOS) to Windows is OK. Ubuntu boot goes to grub shell.

Not sure what to do next ...

- could be that the Ubuntu upgrade affects Grub (due to NVMe SSD)?
- could be a bad SSD, but in that case why Windows has no problem?
- both 18.04.3 and 19.04 use the kernel 5.0.x, could that be linked to the problem?

---

**⇒ Edit ⇒**

It seems [the](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1737934) [problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1678184) [happened](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1746340) to [many](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1805816), and mostly on Samsung NVMe drives.

Following the advice on these pages, I installed Ubuntu (18.04.3, kernel 5.0.0.19) adding the option `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0` to the Grub Linux launch command → was fine.

Then rebooted, adding the same option to the command → fine. And confirmed APST was disabled

```
# nvme get-feature -f 0x0c -H /dev/nvme0

Autonomous Power State Transition Enable (APSTE): Disabled
```

Then did (same session)

```
# apt update
# apt upgrade
```

and a few seconds later... error messages are back, covering the screen, GUI locked, even invading the other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Fx</kbd> consoles... (actually it happens after some time, not just because the command is `apt`)

Not sure if it is a Linux bug, or Samsung ignoring Linux, but I'm stuck!

---

(*edit* +7h

- Removed the Samsung,
- plugged (SATA) a "classic" SSD,
- installed Ubuntu 19.04, made all updates, did a `find / -ls` and other commands, used the graphics, rebooted several times
- → Works!

My next step is to replace the Samsung with a SanDisk NVMe to be purchased tomorrow (have had one in a laptop with Ubuntu for months, no problem at all)

Will keep the page updated!

)

Comment: My Asus is much older Z97, but need multiple changes from defaults to work. I would expect yours since Asus & Intel to be similar. Asus Z97-a BIOS only install (I have only used UEFI).
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296538%20%20%20
Asus-ar screenshots oldfred
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2 Since then UEFI updated multiple times & current default boot is UEFI boot of 18.04. New board may need newest Ubuntu to be well supported. UEFI boot of 20.04 also is working well.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by disabling ASPM.

Add `pcie_aspm=off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` file and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I had the same errors on 18.04 and 20.04. 

CPU: i7-8750H

SSD: ADATA SX6000PNP

Comment: My system worked fine for 1.5 years, but started to crash as described here after I filled it to more than about 300 GB (at least, this seems the most likely trigger).
It seems I also solved it with `pcie_aspm=off`. I am error free for 6 hours now, when previously I got an error within half an hour. I am on AMD TR 2950X, Asrock X399 Taichi and Samsung SSD 970 PRO 512GB (Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983).

Comment: To add some detail, in order to "add" that, it needs to be inserted inside the space-delimited string. The edited line in `/etc/default/grub` looks like this before the edit:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and looks like this after the edit:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm exactly in the same situation with an intel ssd 660p series 512gb.

I've tried a lot of parameters for `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us`, many kernel versions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a failure since updating grub with the following option: `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=6000`

It's been 2 days now, with active gaming, which usually produced the bug within ~30 minutes.

It failed at 0, it still failed at 3000, but 6000 is going strong. And I didn't have to replace the drive.

edit: it still crashes. I was 'fine' in xfce4, i switched back to plasma, and it crashed. i rebooted to xfce again, crashed again (while gaming).

new plan: reinstall on other drive, will use seagate drive for holding files not the OS.